# ffmpeg fps lower than expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run this command.

```
ffmpeg -i out_frames/frame%08d.jpg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -r 23.98 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

It takes a folder of frames (of the input.mp4, but at higher resolution) and makes a video with those frames and also takes the audio from the input.mp4.

Problem is the output.mp4 has a lower/higher fps rate (depending on the clip used) than it should have, resulting in the audio out of sync.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a more precise framerate `-r 24000/1001` instead of `-r 23.98`.

In your case it is also better to put this option before the declaration of the input frames.

If this does not help then it means that your problem it's probably not the framerate issue.

Comment: It does not seem to be the problem, but you can visibly see that the output.mp4 is slower/faster than the original, and that makes the audio progressively more out of sync.

Comment: @DiscepolidiGiais What do you mean by "original"? You also did not say where do these frames `frame%08d.jpg` come from - is that the `input.mp4` divided into frames? Also: try to put `-r 24000/1001` option before the input.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add this in. The .jpg are the upscaled frames of the input.mp4. So the end result is the same video but upscaled, hence why I don't understand why the output is out of sync.

Comment: @DiscepolidiGiais Have you tried to use `-r 24000/1001` before the declaration of the input frames as I suggested above? Also: Why didn't you use ffmpeg's scale filter to do the whole operation in one go? By converting them from `mp4` to external format `jpg` and then again to `mp4` you are losing the quality of the final output.

Comment: I tried to put it up front before and it didn't work for some reason, I tried it again now and it worked. To aswer your question, I have real-esrgan (an enhancing AI) upscaling every single frame one by one from HD to 4K, so that's why. Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: @DiscepolidiGiais I'm glad it worked in the end. I've added the note I suggested in the comment to have full answer.